# Google dataflow failure

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Been testing dataflow for a little while, today I run into a few failures, error messages were:

Causes: (b8a42e32d0888f60): Unable to rename ouput files from gs://clickstream_current/tmp/dataflow/staging/clickstream/8977742977819433140/dax-tmp-2015-04-14_15_58_06-5441905562239213266-S01-1-e70068cb69ef966a/@DAX.json to gs://clickstream_current/tmp/dataflow/staging/clickstream/8977742977819433140/@*.json. Causes: (b8a42e32d0888fdb): Unable to rename "gs://clickstream_current/tmp/dataflow/staging/clickstream/8977742977819433140/dax-tmp-2015-04-14_15_58_06-5441905562239213266-S01-1-e70068cb69ef966a/-shard-00000-of-00940-endshard.json" to "gs://clickstream_current/tmp/dataflow/staging/clickstream/8977742977819433140/-00000-of-00940.json.

Could this be GCS issue? besides the failure there were warning complaining about "Unable delete temporary files from GCS folders" anything I can do to avoid it?

Comment: Is this failure happening consistently? Have you tried your job on a smaller  dataset and/or increasing the number of workers?

Comment: Does the object gs://clickstream_current/tmp/dataflow/staging/clickstream/8977742977819433140/dax-tmp-2015-04-14_15_58_06-5441905562239213266-S01-1-e70068cb69ef966a/-shard-00000-of-00940-endshard.json actually exist?

Comment: What types of Write transforms is your pipeline using? e.g. BigQueryIO, TextIO, AvroIO?

Comment: it didn't happen consistently, the job succeeded when the job run on a smaller dataset (20 times smaller, this worries me)

Comment: when I checked on the file and it didn't exist

Comment: the type of Write transforms of the pipeline is BigQueryIO

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75323/discussion-between-user3924273-and-jeremy-lewi).

Answer (score 1):

We've identified an issue in the service that will cause this failure in certain rare circumstances. We are working on fixing this issue. In the meantime we apologize for the inconvenience. The error is slightly more likely if you are using a BigQueryIO.Write to output your data.